# How to get company data from linkedin without being required to login?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

My end goal is to display the latest LinkedIn post for a company on their company website. I've managed to use the LinkedIn API to pull in updates. However, I have to be logged into the admin LinkedIn account in order for the data to load. If i'm not logged in, it doesn't load anything. The general public needs to be able to see this feed on the website so that won't work.

Is this even possible with the API? Did I do something wrong? Is another method I can try?

Comment: if you have downloaded data from the API, it makes no snesns you need to be logged in to use.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 
this link contains detailed session of how to get your application authenticated and successfully interacting with LinkedIn REST APIs

Comment: The VP of product at linkedin has asked for someone to help you: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:article:8131485506960254045?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28article%3A8131485506960254045%2C6376444128594661376%29

Comment: I think you need to better understand how the API works.
Usually you will make the requests at the back-end and only shown them at the front-end, so there is no problem to be logged-in. I also think that is a good idea to cache this information in you application, so you don't keep asking the API at every call (which will be very bad for performance)

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 ways to get this, both of which need oAuth login. You don't need to be a company admin. You can use the company share API to fetch their latest post by company id. You'd do this on the server-side and serve up the update to the user.

API Reference: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

Example http request using `curl`:

```
curl "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337/updates?oauth2_access_token=your-app-oauth-token-here&start=0&count=1&format=json"
```

You can also do this via the Javascript API but that means the user will login to LinkedIn and use their oauth to fetch the company's latest post.

There's also a v2 api that is available but this should work for what you're describing.

Best wishes,
RV

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually logging in to LinkedIn app, you have to authenticate via OAuth login ([more about OAuth protocol](https://oauth.net/2/)) where you have a client id and secret and you are authenticated based on this.

This info is generally passed in request headers and after authentication you can consume API data.

More can be seen here [Managing company pages: LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages)